# Preciso retornar o texto de um arquivo m3u em listas

Tags: php, javascript, array, string

Tenho um arquivo ".m3u" que preciso retornar alguns dados em lista.

**Exemplo PHP:**

```
<?php 
    $m3u_file = file_get_contents('meuarquivo.m3u');
    preg_match_all('/(tvg-name="(?<name>.*?)".+\n(?P<link>https?:\/\/.+))/', 
    $m3u_file, $channels, PREG_SET_ORDER);
?>

<ul>
    <?php foreach($channels as $m3u_file): ?>
        <li id="title"><?php echo $m3u_file["name"] ?></li>
        <li id="URL"><?php echo str_replace(".ts", ".m3u8", $m3u_file["link"]) ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

**Resultado:**

```html
<ul>    
  <li id="title">A&E</li>
  <li id="URL">http://meucanal.tv:25461/9906</li>

  <li id="title">AMC</li>
  <li id="URL">http://meucanal.tv:25461/9904</li>

  <li id="title">AMC HD</li>
  <li id="URL">http://meucanal.tv:25461/9902</li>

  <li id="title">Animal Planet</li>
  <li id="URL">http://meucanal.tv:25461/9900</li>

  <li id="title">Arte 1</li>
  <li id="URL">http://meucanal.tv:25461/9893</li>

  <li id="title">AXN</li>
  <li id="URL">http://meucanal.tv:25461/9897</li>
</ul>
```

Usando o preg_match_all do PHP consigo esse resultado, mas preciso fazer a mesma coisa usando javascript.
tentei usando o `match()` mas não consegui obter o mesmo resultado.

> Peço desculpa pelos erros, sou novo por aqui kkk

Comment: Não consegui perceber um padrão do que vc quer pegar com o exemplo dado. Sugiro editar a pergunta e detalhar melhor o que deseja e o que já fez.

Answer (score 0):

Caso alguém que tenha a mesma duvida que eu encontre esse post, isso resolveu meu problema...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var myString = `#EXTM3U
            #EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="AeE" tvg-name="A&E" tvg-logo="https://minhalogo.com/img4597.jpg" group-title="Canais Séries",A&E
            http://mylista.com/6782/27khsf/aed
            #EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="AMC" tvg-name="AMC" tvg-logo="https://minhalogo.com/img5332.jpg" group-title="Filmes",AMC
            http://mylista.com/6782/27khsf/amc`;

    var pattern = /(tvg-name="(?<nome>.*?)".+\n(?<url>https?:\/\/.+))/g;
    var match;

    while (match = pattern.exec(myString)) {
        $('body').append(
            `<ul>    
                    <li id="title">` + match[2] + `</li>
                    <li id="URL">` + match[3] + `</li>
                </ul>`
        )
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Tenta esse código, ele vai te retornar exatamente isso que você precisa, mas não estou conseguindo formatar o botão para tocar o video dentro da div com o `video.js`, está me gerando erro.

Se vc souber como se conserta esse probleminha compartilha comigo.
Abraço.

```php
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://url-do-seu-arquivo.m3u");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if (substr($info["http_code"], 0, 2) != 20) {
    die("Could not connect to server. Check username and password");
}

preg_match_all('/(tvg-name="(?<name>.*?)".+tvg-logo="(?<logo>.*?)".+\n(?P<link>https?:\/\/.+))/', $response, $channels, PREG_SET_ORDER);

?>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Logo</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($channels as $channel): ?>
        <tr>
            <body>
            <?php
            $link = $channel["link"];
            
           ?>
            
            <td><button type="button" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="<?php echo $link ?>" /><a  data-value = "<?php echo $link ?>" href="<?php echo $link ?>" target="player"/><img src="<?php echo $channel["logo"] ?>" height="30" width="30" /></button></td>
            <td><?php echo $channel["name"] ?></td>
              
       
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```